# python equivalent of ruby's ASCII-8BIT encoding scheme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, python-2.7, encoding, ascii

I need to encoding something in ASCII-8BIT because it's part of the specification of the program.

The demo code is written in ruby and they have used `Encoding::BINARY`
which is equivalent to `ASCII-8BIT`

Below is the encoding aliases of ruby

```
Encoding.aliases
#=> {"BINARY"=>"ASCII-8BIT", "ASCII"=>"US-ASCII", "ANSI_X3.4-1986"=>"US-ASCII",
      "SJIS"=>"Shift_JIS", "eucJP"=>"EUC-JP", "CP932"=>"Windows-31J"}
```

I need something in python for the ASCII-8BIT. The default ASCII has 0-255 i.e total 8 bits, but im not sure if thats what i need to do.

will `"str".encode("ASCII")` suffice ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an ASCII-8bit encoding; it probably is Latin-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python equivalent is Latin-1; all Unicode codepoints from 0x00 through to 0xFF are mapped one-on-one to bytes with the same value.

Note that this would encode **Unicode** to a bytestring. In Python 2.7, `str` is *already a bytestring* and doesn't need encoding.

Comment: @Anup: hmm, any example input?

Comment: Haha nice one, so if i have "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ", encoding it to Latin-1 will help me identify and to process in a different way. So if i have a normal string, and a Latin-1 encoded string, i need to perform something else. Thats my main goal

Comment: That's just standard ASCII data though.

Comment: @Anup: again,  ASCII would suffice for that.